# Custom user control doesn't catch any mouse events in c#

Tags: c#, user-controls

I create a custom user control and use that in my form.

but it does not capture any mouse event!
what is the problem?
thanks

Comment: Your question is not clear still! add some code

Comment: I created a simple user control (it is just a arrow).In an other project I used it.I  dragged this custom control onto a windows form application
(called mainform). But it dosent react to any mouse event that i wrote to it.

Comment: can u post your code?

Comment: My Problem solved.I should handle mouse events in its own project before be used in the other project. excuse me for my bad english ! my english is not good :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define the event in your custom control

```
private delegate void MyClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e); 
public event MyClickEvent MyClick; 


public void OnMyClickEvent(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                if (MyClick != null)
                        MyClick(sender, e);//execute event
        }
```

Now in MainForm

```
public partial class Form1
{
        public Form1()
        {
                myCustomButton.MyClick += FireThisOnClick;
        }

        private void FireThisOnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
                //this will be executed on click
        }
}
```

Comment: thanks.it worked.I should write events on user controls own project.